# Moodle unable to access using domainName

Tags: apache2, virtual-machine, moodle, php-7

Installing MOODLE_33_STABLE origin/MOODLE_33_STABLE on Ubuntu 16.04.2

I am able to install it and , access it with my vm's ip,

but when i try to change
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://ipaddress' 
to 
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://somerandomname.com'
in config.php,

i am unable to access it using somerandomname.com in my lan.

i have also mapped the vm ip in hosts file of both apache2 and of the other systems in lan, still it shows HTTP ERROR 502, in chrome.
and Host not found when i check the chrome console.

if i am missing something guide me.

i want to access the moodle installed on my VM across my local connection with some domainname rather than the IP .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to try classical debugging:

1. Try to access your moodle instance on the specific port, using eg. telnet

   telnet somerandomname.com 80
2. Delete browser cache or open the URL in your incognito mode
3. Check the apache error log on Ubuntu: /var/log/apache2/error.log.
4. Check out further possibilities which are causing this 502 error: 
   https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939